# Is it ok to provide a concept I idealized and ask if there's a mathematical field that works with it?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

Sometimes, I have ideas about things, and I'm quite sure that there's probably some mathematical field that deals with such a concept. Is it OK to make a question providing a sample of this idea, and ask if there's a mathematical field that deals with this concept?

Also, what tags should I use for such questions? The most adequate I can think of is [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request). I'll also need for suggestions for possible titles. It would be too silly to write *hey guys, what's the name of this thing I thought about?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolutely.  That happens all the time in mathematics, and these connections can sometimes be vital to the problem.

If you don't know which topic you're asking about, you probably won't know the appropriate tags either (at least, until the question is answered).  The meta tags like "reference-request" are only marginally useful at best anyway.  Just make your best guess, and the community can help from there.

---

When I'm stuck for tag ideas, I tend to look at the "Related" column, and see which tags have been used for questions listed there.  The software often makes decent suggestions.

[image: Related column]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.